# Getting error about SQL Parameter is already declared

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a method where I'm adding to a mapper table.  There are only 3 columns: Identity field, CategoryId, and UnitId.  The later two are foreign keys to two other tables.

The List I have contains all three columns within it (CategoryUnit is just a class to store the data).

I'm adding this to the DB via C#.  Here is what I have.

```
private static void ExecuteInsertsIntoCategory_Unit_MappingForSubCategories(
            string sqlInsertStatement, SqlParameterCollection sqlParams,
            List<CategoryUnit> categoryUnitData)
{
            try
            {
                var counter = 0;
                categoryUnitData = categoryUnitData.OrderBy(cud => cud.UnitId)
                                     .ToList();

                foreach (var categoryUnit in categoryUnitData)
                {
                    //Get the parent category
                    var parentCategoryId = categoryUnit.CategoryId;
                    //Go through the categories and get the children of
                    //the parent category
                    var categoryIds = categoryData.Where(cd =>
                                       cd.ParentCategoryId == parentCategoryId)
                                        .Select(cd => cd.CategoryId)
                                        .ToList();
                    //Get the unit
                    var unitId = categoryUnit.UnitId;
                    tempUnit = unitId;

                    if (categoryIds.Count > 0)
                    {
                        using (var sqlCommand =
                               new SqlCommand(sqlInsertStatement, sqlCon))
                        {
                            foreach (var categoryId in categoryIds)
                            {
                                tempCategory = categoryId;
                                foreach (SqlParameter sqlParam in sqlParams)
                                {
                                    switch (sqlParam.ParameterName)
                                    {
                                        case "@CategoryId":
                                            sqlCommand.Parameters
                                                      .AddWithValue
                                                      (sqlParam.ParameterName,
                                                      categoryId);
                                            break;
                                        case "@UnitId":
                                            sqlCommand.Parameters
                                                      .AddWithValue
                                                      (sqlParam.ParameterName,
                                                      unitId);
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }

                                //Both must exist in order to add a record
                                if (categoryId != 0 && unitId != 0)
                                {

                                    //Execute sql and clear out
                                    sqlCon.Open();
                                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    sqlCon.Close();

                                    counter++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine(counter + " row(s) added to "
                                          + "Category_Unit_Mapping for "
                                          + "Subcategories");
            }
            //Something went wrong
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error in SQL Insert Into "
                                 + "Category_Unit_Mapping for Subcategories: "
                                 + ex.Message);
            }
            //Close out sql connection
            finally
            {
                if (sqlCon.State != ConnectionState.Closed) sqlCon.Close();
            }
        }
```

When my code gets to this method, I get the following error.

"The variable name '@CategoryId' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure."

I have previous methods that are similar but they haven't had any issues.  Not quite sure what to make of this.  Btw, all the data is scrubbed for duplicates.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I see that you have it. See: var parentCategoryId = categoryUnit.CategoryId;

Comment: At a hunch, I'd say it's the for each loop within your `SqlCommand` using block.  If it loops more than once, you're using the same SqlCommand and therefore have already created the `@CategoryID` parameter (and the `@UnitId` as well).

Comment: Have you checked your SQL parameter collection to ensure CategoryID isn't declared more than once?

Comment: To follow up on my previous comment, try creating the parameters collection before the for each loop, and then simply set the values of the parameters each time you go through the loop.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your nested foreach loops in the debugger to make sure you're not actually trying to declare @CategoryId more than once?  It looks like that could happen fairly easily.

Comment: Tim, I suspect you're right. In fact, I know you are right because I just tested it.  Thanks.  If you can post I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding your SQL parameters inside a loop to the same command object which already has the parameters added. Remove the following loop:

```
foreach (SqlParameter sqlParam in sqlParams)
```

Then instead of adding parameters, set the parameter values:

```
sqlCommand.Parameters["@CategoryId"] = categoryId;
sqlCommand.Parameters["@UnitId"] = unitId;
```

Then before you enter your larger for loop, add the parameters to your command once:

```
using (var sqlCommand =
    new SqlCommand(sqlInsertStatement, sqlCon))
    {
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(sqlParams["@CategoryId"]);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(sqlParams["@UnitId"]);
        foreach (var categoryId in categoryIds)
...
```

Comment: I gave you credit because Tim hasn't come to claim it.  You were technically right also, so thanks.